# Identifying an IC named ID2J

Tags: power-supply, power, identification, switching

Recently I was working on a 5V switching power supply project and I found the best PCB for building it. But in the middle I got confused when I saw an IC with the letters `ID2J`.

It has 5 pins like an op-amp or an optoisolator SMD.  I searched for it and found nothing, no manufacturer and no datasheet. On the PCB silkscreen it's called `IC1`.

Does any one know what kind of IC is this?

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: That is a SOT23-5 package.

Comment: IC1 means it probably one of the first stages of the schematic. Often they are power input/filtering/management schematics, so this is possibly a low power linear regulator or a reset supervisor, or similar IC.

Comment: Also what's with the crap photo quality? It would really help for a wider shot to see the context of the IC, and it's surrounding components. Also, how is this a 5V switching supply project, how did you just "find the best PCB"?

Comment: I zoomed in for the IC letters. so that makes it crap. I will be really happy if you give me a helpful answer...

Comment: Well my Google-fu spent 10 minutes trying to help you, searching all manner of things, and I have no reasonable result. Best thing we can do here is reverse engineer from circuit location and experience and help you identify the basic operation of the IC, and then you can go find a new one.

Comment: Also it's clearly ID2J but the rest is crap, zoom out and tell us about the PCB it's on, and why you are trying to hack it up.

Comment: Thank you. If I unsolder the IC how can I identify the chip operation? if that's an optoisolator or an op-amp.

Comment: I needed a small power supply for my project and this board was the solution.

Comment: that board was already a power supply? And how do you know that IC is an opto-isolator or an op-amp? It's highly unlikely..

Comment: Ah, so this is connected to mains AC power, through some transformers? this could be (judging from the amount of passives nearby) indeed a feedback op-amp

Comment: I have drawn a schematic from this I think that would be helpful.

Comment: If you have worked out the pin connections to various components that helps yes, some devices have fairly standard pin configurations so someone will spot it immidiately

Comment: Could be a voltage regulator like http://smdcode.com/en/smd/code/d2j-aic1746-285gj5-linear-voltage-regulator-integrated-circuit-13134/ in general omitting the first or last digits when googling helps sometimes.

Comment: WOW...How did you find that thank you it was really helpful!!

Comment: A rather interesting looking open loop powersupply.

Answer (score 1):

Searches on ID2J seem to draw a complete blank.

However a search on 1D2J brings up this page...
http://m.cnledw.com/bbs/topic/view/163682.html

which contains the entry

表面代码丝印 1DYJ 1DZJ 1D0J 1D1J 1D2J 1D3J 1D4J 1D5J 1D6J 1D7J 1D8J 1D9J 封装SOT23-6封装SOT23-5封装SOT23是什么型号?

unfortunately I can't get you any closer than that ... maybe someone else can?
May be misleading because the mark does look like "I" rather than "1"

Comment: yes, I agree it does look more like an I than a 1.

Comment: yes that's an "I".